# word cloud or visualization in foreign languages

Tags: python, internationalization, visualization, word-cloud

I tried to use amueller's wordcloud (https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/) for creating word cloud from Nepali Language (https://setopati.com/). Example of text:

```
string1="""आजको छापा English Logo गृहपृष्ठ राजनीति समाज विचार किनमेल कला खेलकुद घुमफिर ब्लग साहित्यपाटी ग्लोबल फोटो ग्यालरी कस्तो छ प्रधानमन्त्रीको स्वास्थ्य? सरकारले सिण्डिकेट हटाएपछि देशैभरका टिकट काउन्टर बन्द उपेन्द्र यादवले फेरि दिए स\u200cंविधान नस्वीकारेको धम्की पौडेलले देउवालाई भने– प्रधानमन्त्री नभए पनि गणेशमानलाई जनताले पूज्छन्, तपाईंलाई कस्ले पुज्छ? ३३ किलो सुन गायब प्रकरण : यस्तो छ गोरे – प्रहरी ‘कनेक्सन’ चीनलाई उपहार दिने गैँडा फेला परेन काठमाडौंमा भारतका ३ पूर्वराजदूत गाउँ चम्किए, सदरमुकाम खस्किए यी हुन् मोबाइल नबोक्ने ‘ठूला मान्छे’ विगतको पोल खुल्ने डरले भगाइयो गोरेलाई गुराँस टिप्नेलाई ‘जंगलमै कारबाही’ नेपाल भ्रमणमा आफ्नै कार ल्याउँदैछन् मोदीले सिंहदरबारभित्र कोठा खोज्दै प्रधानमन्त्री कार्यालय डाक्टरले ‘भ्वाइस रेस्ट’ गर्न भनेका गच्छदार ३ घन्टा ५ मिनेट बोले, शुक्रबार थप १ घन्टा बोल्ने अभियुक्तसँग नाम थर मिल्दा निर्दोषलार्इ जेल सांसदहरूले व्यापार-व्यावसाय गर्न नपाउने सरकारको नीति तथा कार्यक्रम तयार, ८ प्रतिशतको आर्थिक वृद्धिको लक्ष्य स्वतन्त्र हुन सम्बन्धविच्छेद गर्ने क्रम बढ्यो मोदीको भ्रमण तालिका बनाउनै हम्मे बोली फेरिएन प्रधानमन्त्रीको: दुई बर्षपछि पनि उस्तै भाषण पञ्चायतदेखि नै\xa0सुन र शक्तिको सम्बन्ध! यी हुन् सुन तस्करीका ७ घुम्ती एमाले–माओवादीले १० हजार युवालाई मार्क्सवाद पढाउने साउदीमा नेपाली युवालाई मृत्युदण्डको फैसला सरकारी निकायले १३ अर्ब नतिर्दा गुठी थला ‘पूर्वी नेपाल भूकम्प उच्च जोखिममा’ सामुदायिक स्कुलमा पनि निजीजस्तै शुल्क सिंचाई विभागमा दिनहुँ चल्छ जुवातास गृहपृष्ठ ब्लग साहित्यपाटी पाठक विचार दसैं सामग्री छापाबाट फिड """
```

Can anybody advise me how to generate wordcloud from foreign language?

```
    wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=300, background_color = 'white', relative_scaling=1, 
                          width=1500, height=1000, colormap='plasma').generate(string1)#generate_from_frequencies(linklist)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter what language the strings are representing...

Comment: yeah, I get picture as above. any thoughts?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, provided more words / reproducible code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a font that supports the characters you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

I can generate with this :

```
string1="""setopatI kaiNtpur sgrmatha pin  nepal"""
```

However straight from Nepali langauge to Wordcloud seems challenging

[image]